# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Image Bug/Errors?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Since few days ago, I am not able to pull nginx ingress images from `gcr` repo like `gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.15` nor am I able to pull the image `quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0`. I always get the status code `403` and status `ImagePullBackOff`. When I upgrade the image version to `quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.16.0` or `0.16.2` I get the following pod error: `[dumb-init] /ingress-nginx-controller: No such file or directory`. What happened?

EDIT: It seems to be an error with the docker deamon in the cluster as I was able to pull the image with the local docker installation and then push it manually into my registry.

Comment: what version of kubernetes are you running?

Comment: `403` means you have some problem with authorization, do you change any kind of policies or service accounts?

Comment: @suren I am running 1.9.7

Comment: @NickRak Actually yes, but I only added a service account. Anyways, what I dont get is, as this is a public registry repo, why does the authorization matter? Does it send them my cluster auth and the registry rejects because it wants me to be anonymous?

Comment: [Techradar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6360083/techradar) As I see [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/google-containers/GLOBAL/nginx-ingress-controller?gcrImageListsize=50) this image doesn't exist. may you pull it from another place

Comment: @NickRak The `0.9.0-beta.15` image does exist in GCR. I also tried pulling newer versions from `quay.io`...

Comment: I tried to pull images from both registry and all works fine could try to use something like `--disable-content-trust`. from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by building the image on my own and adding it to the registry.